# Get the value and position of column based on a variable

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements, apply

Here is a code to replicate my dataset.

```
col1=c(20,15,NA,NA)
col2=c(30,30,6,NA)
col3=c(40,NA,7,NA)
col4=c(NA,60,8,NA)
col5=c(60,75,9,NA)
check=c(40,35,10,NA)

df=data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,check)
```

I would like to get the position of the column which is greater than the "check" column.If possible, I would also like to get the value of that column as well.

Here is a function that I create, which does not work:

```
fun=function(x){
        j1=which(x>df$check)[1]
        if(is.na(j1)){
                NA
        }
        else if (!is.na(j1)){
                j1
        }
}

df$test=apply(df[,1:5],1,fun)
```

My final data frame would look like this:

```
col1=c(20,15,NA,NA)
col2=c(30,30,6,NA)
col3=c(40,NA,7,NA)
col4=c(NA,60,8,NA)
col5=c(60,75,9,NA)
check=c(40,35,10,NA)
test=c(5,4,NA,NA)
value=c(60,60,NA,NA)
df=data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,check, test,value)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the column index.  Using the sequence of rows and the column index, we can extract the elements from the first five columns.

```
#created a logical matrix
m1 <- df[1:5] > df$check
#changed the NA elements to FALSE
m1[is.na(m1)] <- FALSE
#used max.col to get the column index.  For rows that have all FALSE
#we change it to 0 after multiplying with the logical index of `rowSums(..`.
v1 <- max.col(m1, 'first')*(rowSums(m1)!=0)
#reconvert the 0 values to NA
test <-  NA^(v1==0)*v1
#extract the elements using row/column index
value <- df[1:5][cbind(1:nrow(df), test)]
#cbind the new vectors to get the desired output.
df <- cbind(df, test, value)
df
#   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 check test value
#1   20   30   40   NA   60    40    5    60
#2   15   30   NA   60   75    35    4    60
#3   NA    6    7    8    9    10   NA    NA
#4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA    NA
```

---

Or both the columns can be created using `apply`.  Though, this may be compact, it could be less efficient compared to the first solutio.  We loop through the rows using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, get the numeric index of elements 1 to 5 that are greater than the 6th value, subset the first occurence (`[1]`, if there are no elements, this will automatically convert that to NA).  Based on this index, we subset the element, concatenate, get the transpose and assign to new columns in 'df'.

```
df[c('test', 'value')] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
             i1 <- which(x[1:5]>x[6])[1]
              c(i1, x[i1])}))
```

Comment: Constructing `test` as `max.col(m1, 'first')*NA^(rowSums(m1)==0)` saves you from dealing with the intermediate variables. Maybe harder to explain, though. Also, it might be better to just add the new cols to `df` instead of `cbind`ing a new one, `df[c("test","value")] <- list(test,value)`. Going to add commentary on apply vs max.col? The latter is more popular on SO, seems.

Comment: @Frank I thought about using it in a single line, but it becomes little hard to understand.